# How to rename bunch of users' DisplayNames using Powershell in Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange, powershell

I have bunch of users which DisplayNames I changed mistakenly to some string (for example: xyz)

But there is one field called Name which has FirstName and Lastname. 
What I want is take all users who has xyz in it and them change DisplayName to the corresponding Name.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {DisplayName -like "*xyz*"} |
```

This gives me the array I need whose DisplayNames i need to change.
What I add after the "pipe" ?

I googled a lot, however couldn't come up with the answer.

I tried:

```
Set-Mailbox -DisplayName $_.Name
```

However it says

```
Cannot bind parameter 'DisplayName' to the target. .... cannot be null/empty.
```

How can I set DisplayName to the same value as Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$mbxs = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {DisplayName -like "*FirstName Lastname*"}
$mbxs | foreach { %{Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -DisplayName $_.Name}}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

There's no `$_` variable when piping from one cmdlet to the next directly. So `Set-Mailbox` is seeing a $null for the DisplayName parameter and failing. Try wrapping the Set-Mailbox command in a `ForEach-Object` call (alias `%`) to get that `$_` variable, like so:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {DisplayName -like "*xyz*"} | % {Set-Mailbox  -Identity $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -DisplayName $_.Name}
```

Comment: I did the following: `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {DisplayName -like "*Firstname Lastname*"} | % {Set-Mailbox -DisplayName $_.Name}` however

Comment: it says `Pipeline not executed because a pipeline is already executin`

Comment: Sorry, you DO need "-Identity $_.PrimarySmtpAddress" in the Set-Mailbox call. I will edit the answer to reflect the full command.